# Why would a network interface be detected by nmcli and ip, but not by iw?

Tags: networking, wifi, network-interface, ip, iw

Running `ip link` I get the output

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: wlp6s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 28:b2:bd:97:d6:50 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlxd0374514b161: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d0:37:45:14:b1:61 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Similarly, `ls /sys/class/net` lists `lo  wlp6s0  wlxd0374514b161`. However, `iw dev` prints out a single interface:

```
phy#0
    Interface wlp6s0
        ifindex 2
        wdev 0x1
        addr 28:b2:bd:97:d6:50
        type managed
        txpower 0.00 dBm
```

Similarly, `nmcli dev` gives

```
DEVICE           TYPE      STATE      CONNECTION 
wlxd0374514b161  wifi      connected  awesomeConnection       
lo               loopback  unmanaged  --         
wlp6s0           wifi      unmanaged  --
```

I thought `iw dev` was also supposed to print all available network interfaces? Is this not the case? Why is one interface not shown in the output of `iw dev`?

Here, `wlp6s0` is the internal network adapter of my laptop, which is disabled because faulty, while `wlxd0374514b161` is a (working...?) USB network adapter. About said USB `lsusb` tells me

```
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0bda:8179 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8188EUS 802.11n Wireless Network Adapter
```

while the drivers of the two network interfaces are

```
$ DEV=wlxd0374514b161
$ readlink -f /sys/class/net/$DEV/device/driver
/sys/bus/usb/drivers/r8188eu
$ readlink -f /sys/class/net/wlp6s0/device/driver
/sys/bus/pci/drivers/iwlwifi
```

I add this information because, considering [this question on superuser](https://superuser.com/q/1049960/376608), and [iw not finding usb wifi dongle](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/386667/iw-not-finding-usb-wifi-dongle), it might be relevant to the issue.

Comment: Does the output of `iw list` include all your devices?

Comment: @fra-san I don't think so, though I'm not sure. It lists all details about a `Wyphy phy0`, but it doesn't give me the name of the interface. I suppose this is still `wlp6s0`, given that `iw dev` lists this interface as `phy#0`?

Comment: Did you try `sudo iw dev`?

Comment: @waltinator yes, no difference (also, is there a reason one should expect to need sudo to list network interfaces?)